# Get and Refresh a Google Cloud Storage Access Token using C#

Tags: rest, c#-4.0, oauth-2.0, json.net, google-cloud-storage

I have some code that I am using and I get the credentials created, but when I try to create a bucket or upload a file to the Google Cloud Storage API, I get the error:

```
The access token has expired and could not be refreshed. Errors: refresh error, refresh error, refresh error
```

When I google this error I get vague Google links telling me what I have to do but no examples.

Here is the line of code that throws the error:

```
var bucket = storageClient.CreateBucket(projectId, bucketName);
```

here is my Json file:

```
  "type": "authorized_user",
  "client_id": "clientId",
  "project_id": "projectId",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_secret": "clientSecret",
  "redirect_uris": [ "https://localhost:44349//RedirectPage.aspx" ]
```

How do I get/refresh an access token using C#?

Thank you for any help!

Dave

Comment: When the credentials are created, the Refresh Token must be saved. Then use the Refresh Token to request a new Access Token (or Identity Token). This article shows how to refresh a token using curl and HTTP requests, which makes it easy to translate to C#: https://www.jhanley.com/google-oauth-2-0-testing-with-curl-refresh-access-token/ However, from the error message you are trying to use a raw token without a management layer. I recommend using the SDKs and not try to directly manipulate OAuth tokens unless you understand OAuth well (or are trying to master OAuth).

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley I will take a look at the link that you provided.